# How to check if URL is within your web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC4 C# web application, using FormsAuthentication.
Inside a controller account with `Login` action has parameter `ReturnUrl`.
What is the best way to check that `ReturnUrl` is an url of my web app. To be safe of someone messing a round with the `ReturnUrl` parameter (anti-phishing).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Url.IsLocalUrl("url")`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.islocalurl(v=vs.108).aspx